# What does const means in auto return declaration with trailing return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, trailing-return-type

I need to return a const reference from the function. This code does the thing:

```
auto test()->add_lvalue_reference<const int>::type
{
    static int i{50};
    return i;
}

int & i{test()}; // doesn't compile
```

But this snippet, that looks painfully similar, gives an incorrect result:

```
auto const test()->add_lvalue_reference<int>::type
{
    static int i{50};
    return i;
}

int & i{test()}; // compiles thougth test() returned a const
```

I moved keyword `const` from the type declaration to the return declaration.

At first, I thought, that after deduction the function signature became in the second case:

```
int & const test(); // not valid - const qualifiers cannot be applied to int&
```

This is not a valid c++. But with `auto` specifier it compiles.

So my question is what does `const` means in function return type with auto trailing return? Or maybe it's discarded?

Comment: Congratulations, you've found a compiler bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
auto const test()->add_lvalue_reference<int>::type
```

This is ill-formed, see [[dcl.fct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#2) (in the case where a *trailing-return-type* is used, "`T` shall be the single *type-specifier* `auto`").

Comment: You're right. I'd need to test first on different compilers. Clang and msvc refuse to compile in opposite to gcc.